# Почему никто не голосует за вопросы про LyX?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, репутация

Так, стало интересно. Почему никто не голосует по этим вопросам? Пишу, можно сказать, эксклюзив: поди, найди в Рунете инфу про LyX, а репутация стоит на месте.

Мне, конечно, скоро она будет почти постольку-поскольку: просто расскажу всё, что знаю про эту прогу, а больше на компьютерном форуме мне рассказывать не о чем, но тем не менее...

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрел ваш один ответ: [Как в LyX настраивать прямой и обратный поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1066935/28748)

Только не обижайтесь, я хочу искренне вам помочь.

Взгляните на свой топик отрешенно, глазами человека, который читает вопрос и может быть часть ответа. 
Вопрос должен зацепить внимание за 5-10 секунд, сначала информативным заголовком в общем потоке, а затем началом подачи информации в ответе. Увы, это реальность, вам дано всего 5-10 секунд, чтобы заинтересовать. Сейчас мир перегружен потоком информации.

Вы не задумывались, как работают мастера рекламы, в чём их успех? Мы все ненавидим рекламу, устали от неё, но тем не менее люди очень часто покупают именно те товары, которые увидели в рекламе.  Почему?

Потому что используются основные инстинкты. Для женщин это: мой муж, мой ребенок, моя семья, моё здоровье и так далее. Поэтому в рекламе ключ к успеху слово, - **моё**

Для компьютерщиков основной инстинкт - узнать, изучить, что-то новое, что поможет их успеху.

Теперь взгляните на свой вопрос глазами человека, который бороздит океаны информации

> Прежде всего, всех с Рождеством Христовым! Собственно, у меня это
>   несеолько лет не получалось. Сейчас я это умею делать. Вот, хочу
>   поделиться

Скорее всего это вызовет в лучшем случае улыбку, но может быть и негатив, за зря
 потраченные 5 секунд :)

А вот, если бы вы обыграли в подаче вопроса, ту информацию, которая есть в описании метки, то это могло бы вызвать интерес:

> использовать во всех вопросах связанных с LyX - свободным процессором
>   документов, основанным на системе компьютерной вёрстки LaTeX. LyX
>   является кроссплатформенным программным обеспечением и имеет готовые
>   сборки для Linux, Windows, Mac OS X.

**Подача материала в ответе**

У вас слепой текст, без абзацов. Это напрягает, утомляет, как людей, обладающих скорочтением, так и людей с пониженным зрением, да в общем то всех.

В подаче информации нужно стараться избегать очень подробного описания, но не упустить важных моментов. Люди сами смогут разобраться в мелочах, но будут вам благодарны за те нюансы, которые вы узнали в процессе экспериментов с продуктом.

Слова воспринимаются по разному, даже отточенные формулировки. Поэтому необходимо иллюстрировать важные моменты скринами с экрана. Да и визуальная информация всегда воспринимается лучше, чем слова.

Comment: По поводу подачи. Я думаю, что тому человеку, которому действительно нужна и важна эта тема, нет абсолютно никакого дела до формы, остальным же нужно просто сдерживать себя, проходя мимо и понимая, что, в принципе, я делаю нужное дело, Хотя, да, вы правы: людей в этой теме здесь мало.

Comment: @mathem вы не совсем точно поняли основной посыл. Если вам нужно, чтобы читали именно ваш материал, останавливались на нем, а может быть заинтересовать новых людей, кто ещё не пробовал. Сейчас читать тяжело в том виде, который сейчас есть.

Comment: Ну, по-другому не знаю, как. Да и некому тут много читать: математиков, физиков здесь раз, два и обчелся. Просто раньше почему-то при той же форме подачи репа быстрее росла, больше чувствовал, что нужно.

Comment: @mathem а вы попробуйте, подкорректируйте, хотя бы вопрос. А то правда выглядит как-то ..... не серьезно.

Comment: К сожалению, я не писатель.

Comment: > В подаче информации нужно стараться избегать очень подробного описания - наоборот, я исхожу из того, что мой читатель - человек, как и я, не очень искушен в компах и вникать в эти компы для него - дело десятое. Все, что ему нужно - это создать какой-нибудь нормально выглядящий файл со своими формулами наиболее удобным способом (хотя бы сто раз язык переключать не надо, и то большо-ое дело). И, кстати, ориентируясь на такого читателя, я вообще на жалею сил на иллюстрации, так что чей-то здесь упрек, что их мало - ИМХО, совсем мимо.

Comment: @mathem прошу прощения насчет иллюстраций, это получилась невольная проверка вас, насчет этих 10 секунд внимания. Вы с третьего раза заметили только. Значит первый раз читали мой пост не внимательно, как раз как я описывал, как будут читать ваш ответ. Я тоже не смог пойти дальше первого экрана ваша поста, когда читал в первый раз вашу статью, потом то уже заметил, что есть иллюстрации. Решил для себя, если автор возмутится с первого раза, значит внимательно читает.  Если нет, то нет. Так, что видите, все мы такие, поэтому надо прикладывать больше усилий для привлечения внимания

Comment: Я внимательно читал  ваш пост, просто, помимо вас я отвечаю еще нескольким людям и думаю сразу про всех. У меня выше потому же и опечатка была. А если эта инфа мне вообще никуда, так я и заходить в эту тему не буду.

Comment: @mathem согласен с вами, оставляйте как есть, если считаете, что всё нормально. Может потом зайдет тот, кому позарез нужно и будет полезно и проплюсует. вас в с благодарностью Но ведь вы спросили почему люди не плюсуют сейчас и мы постарались ответить, посоветовать вам, как нам кажется со стороны.

Answer (score 4):

Вы частично сами уже ответили на свой вопрос. Но могу предположить несколько причин:

- Тема узкоспециализированная. Что по метке [lyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lyx), что по [latex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) вопросов мало. Метки мало кому интересны, вот и не плюсуют поэтому возможно.
- Не плюсуют (а некоторые минусуют), вполне вероятно, по причине того, что считают, что материал откуда-то скопирован.
- Вы за несколько дней сразу много вопросом cоздали, возможно это кому-то не понравилось.
- Есть участники, которые в принципе не любят самоответы.

Comment: Да, это действительно скопировано, но только с моего блога. Там, где я что-то подсмотрел, я даю ссылки. Все остальное изучено честно мной. Я хочу создать в нескольких местах источники инфы по этому поводу.. А много вопросов за несколько дней потому, что хочу побыстрее закончить, чтобы начать другое дело. По поводу самоответов мне здесь же и посоветовали такую форму.

Comment: @mathem самоответы - это хорош и поощряется! Важное не голоса, а то, что ваше дело в будущем может помочь многим. Поэтому, я бы не стал так сильно зацикливаться на голосах.

Comment: Я для этого все и затеял. Но только много писать в пустоту... Думаешь, а оно вообще-то кому-то надо? Да вообще все так сложно и тупиково...

Comment: @mathem я сам свой [блог](https://suvitruf.ru/) веду и понимаю о чём вы. Бывают периоды, когда не понимаешь, нужно это кому-то или нет. Тут уже каждый для себя сам решает, как ему быть. В моём случае, я знаю, что есть люди, которым моё дело интересно и помогает. Возможно и вы в будущем таких найдёте. Главное не бросать дело на полпути.

Comment: Да, собственно, конкретно здесь дело уже где-то около 3/4. Копирую, повторюсь, с моего блога, отсюда: https://matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_83.html. Сейчас готовлю к публикации здесь копию статьи *LyX; использование файлов .bat*. Вот допишу ту серию статей и все, мне тут делать нечего: я ж не компьютерщик, я, типа, математик... Неудавшийся... Неудачник. Может, хоть что-то исходящее от меня кому-то будет кому-то полезно. Кстати, по поводу той ссылки. Я вот думаю, как содержание статей там 
LyX: Общие замечания. Часть 1, 2, 3 писать сюда?

Comment: Ведь форма тех статей категорически не подходит для публикации здесь. Ничего не подскажите? После того, как здесь закончу, думаю закончить аналогичную серию статей на Хабре. А потом, когда-нибудь, может, напишу еще один блог. А в скольки местах публикуете вы свои находки?

Comment: @mathem яндекс.дзен, dtf, хабр. По поводу частей 1,2,3 можете у людей в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) поинтересоваться.

Comment: В чате скажут, чтоб я тут вообще не писал про это.

Comment: @mathem да нет, там довольно доброжелательный народ сидит)

Comment: А я обратное и не утверждаю.  Просто мне здесь довольно часто здесь говорят, что то, про что я здесь пишу, не совсем по теме этого форума.

Answer (score 2):

Могу добавить ещё одну единицу данных, как человек, который плюсует
большинство вопросов, связанных с L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X
и T<sub>E</sub>X:  Меня попросту не интересуют *WYSIWYG*-редакторы
работы с T<sub>E</sub>X.  Я работаю с ним в *Vim*, и меня это
совершенно устраивает.  Поэтому я не отслеживаю метку `lyx`
и попросту не вижу этих вопросов.

Comment: А вы пробовали?

Comment: Нет и не вижу смысла даже пробовать.  Я достаточно **страдал**
с *Microsoft Office,* *OpenOffice,* *LibreOffice,* а также с целой тучей очень плохих *WYSIWYG*-редакторов в браузере *(Slack!).*
Я хочу видеть две вещи: код и результат.  Промужуточной «фантазии на
тему» от авторов *WYSIWYG*-редакторов мне не нужно.

Comment: Так это совсем не Офис, я сам его попробовал, мне его даром для математики не надо. Про Опен не знаю, но, думаю, тоже дрянь. А так позиция "не читал, но осуждаю" она, знаете, тоже так себе... Скажите, пожалуйста, вы в ТеХ много формул набираете?

Comment: Скорее «читал этот жанр, и мне не понравилось».  Формулы сейчас уже почти не печатаю, работаю исключительно с «гуманитарским» текстом.  Но когда печатал, проблем не испытывал.  (Ну и да, комментарии на Мете СО — не место для вербовки сторонников :-)

Comment: А если без формул, так вам и офис, скорее всего за глаза. Извините, но, скорее всего, это обсуждение просто не для вас. Без обид.