# Ответ на свой вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Продолжительное время разбирался с инструментом для нагрузочного тестирования. Получил полезный опыт и хотелось бы им поделиться, т.к. на RU SO нет даже упоминания этого.

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше сделать?
2. Приемлимо ли такое на RU SO?
3. Есть уже такие примеры ?

Comment: Да, приемлемо. Вероятно, у вас будет не один вопрос, а сразу несколько: не валите всё в одну кучу, а постарайтесь распилить на отдельные конкретные вопросы. Примеры в моём профиле, из последних: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1066777/213987), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1065570/213987), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1062516/213987). Отдельно посмотрите на [механизм ассоциаций](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/213987), возможно вы тоже что-то находили непереведённое на en so.

Comment: @Vadim Prokopchuk Посмотрите вот это [обсуждение по аналогичному вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9979/28748). Только там автор спрашивал, почему не оценивают его труд. Но там тоже был самоответ. Самоответы приветствуются, весь вопрос, как это сделать, чтобы привлечь внимание..

Comment: Я бы предложил закрыть как дубль, подобные темы всплывали ([пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/213987)), да и [в справке есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Аккумуляция знаний на SO самоответами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6300/%d0%90%d0%ba%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-so-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)